# How to generate one file with polyfilled code and one without it in vue js as webcomponent

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs, web-component

I created a Vue app as a web component. Created it using the script

```
vue-cli-service build  --target wc  --name email-compose ./src/views/EmailCompose.vue
```

I have done polyfills. So my output is a javascript file with transpilled code. This is useful for browsers like IE 11. But its not needed for modern browsers like chrome. So is there any way to generate one polyfilled file and one without it.

```
vue-cli-service build --modern
```

This code would be useful if I was simply building.As I am building it as a web component, this is not useful.

so guys please suggest some way to generate one polyfilled file and one without it.

Thanks in advance.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-component-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "prebuild": "babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions node_modules/@vue/web-component-wrapper/dist/vue-wc-wrapper.js -o node_modules/@vue/web-component-wrapper/dist/vue-wc-wrapper.js",
    "build:production": "vue-cli-service build  --target wc  --name email-compose ./src/views/EmailCompose.vue",
    "build": "npx vue-cli-service build  --target wc --inline-vue --name email-compose-legacy ./src/views/EmailCompose.vue",
    "test": "npm run build && npm run build:prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "@vue/web-component-wrapper": "^1.2.0",
    "webcomponentsjs": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/web-component-wrapper": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes": "^0.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets:  ["@babel/preset-env"], 
    overrides: [
      {
        presets: [
          ["@babel/preset-env", {   targets: { ie: "11" } }],
        ],
      }]
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['@babel/polyfill','./src/main.js'],   
    },
    module: {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: file => (
            /node_modules/.test(file)
        ),
        use: [
            { loader: "babel-loader" },
        ],
    },
    vue: {
        loaders: {
            js: 'babel-loader'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out. Its been two days